# What books have information on Grey Mountains Dwarves and Troll Hunters?

Tags: wfrp-2e, warhammer, wfrp

I have gotten Dwarf from Grey Mountains, who is Troll Hunter. I would like to extensively read about Great Mountain city or fort, but cannot find such an information. Also I would like to learn more about Dwarven code of life and Dammaz Kron (book of offences) and Troll Hunter (I have seen brief description in main book).

Can you please help me and direct in what books if even possible I can find that information?

I am talking about *Warhammer Fantasy* 2nd edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Dwarves are neglected in WFRP 2nd!

It's horrible how the dwarves were neglected, there is no Dwarf book at all! So a lot we have about Trollhunters and Dammaz Korn will come from other sources - **especially** the dwarf codices for Warhammer Armies and Warhammer Fantasy as well as other editions of WFRP. Too bad, as the Dwarves had had their own 1st edition WFRP book in *Stone and Steel*, which is quite excellent

A lot of the more relevant Warhammer sources are collated in the articles on the [Grey Mountains](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Grey_Mountains) and the [Grey Dwarves](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Grey_Dwarf), which might act as primers and they contain pointers to the correct sources and even other articles. The [Dwarf](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Dwarfs) Article is particularly excellent, and together with adjacent articles worth a heavy read. Don't forget to  brush up your [Khazalid](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Khazalid)!

But then again, you said "Troll Hunter"... there's no Troll Hunters as far as I can tell, but there are "[Troll Slayers](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Troll_Slayer)", the first entry into the [Slayer path](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Slayers), depicted in the Career Compendium. There's a little more lore on them in that book. They are also called "[Trolldrengi](https://whfb-de.lexicanum.com/wiki/Trolldrengi)", and if you **really** are into Trollslayers... look no further than the 1999 first installment of the Felix & Gotrik series: ["Trollslayer" by William King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trollslayer).

If you know German, the Lexicanum also can help and assist in finding the lore sources, as they often have additional sources to the Warhammer Wiki. For example, [Dammaz Kron](https://whfb-de.lexicanum.com/wiki/Dammaz_Kron) is a book heavily referred to in the army books and is on the Warhammer Wiki only cataloged as the [Great Book of Grudges](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Book_of_Grudges). It's less a *code of life*, it is a huge list that tells exactly which dwarf got harmed by a member of a species and how, and who needs to die to allow *striking* the grudge from the book. It's pretty much the Dwarves' "Naughty List", but getting an entry on it means you and your children will get killed for ending on it.

Comment: Yes you are right - Troll Slayers. I was translating it from my language.

Comment: I know a little bit of German, but I can always use translator ;)